# Почему Dns.GetHostEntry бросает исключение? Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c#, сокет, dns

Ошибка происходит при любом способе ввода аргумента в `GetHostEntry`.

```
Dns.GetHostEntry(IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"))
```

или даже так

```
Dns.GetHostEntry("0.0.0.0)
```

[image]

Comment: А что вам не понятно из текста ошибки?

Comment: Может быть вам нужно использовать `IPAddress.Any` без `Dns.GetHostEntry().AddressList`?

Answer (score 0):

```cs
var addr = IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0");
```